# Number of ways to distribute identical balls into identical bins

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I have a question which I expected to be quite famous and common, yet I haven't found much...

> How many ways are there to distribute $k$ identical balls into $n$ identical bins?

For example $(k, n) = (6, 4)$:

\begin{align}
6 &= (6, 0, 0, 0) \\
&= (5, 1, 0, 0) \\
&= (4, 2, 0, 0) \\
&= (4, 1, 1, 0) \\
&= (3, 3, 0, 0) \\
&= (3, 2, 1, 0) \\
&= (3, 1, 1, 1) \\
&= (2, 2, 2, 0) \\
&= (2, 2, 1, 1)
\end{align}

So there are $9$ ways how to distribute the balls. I've went through this site but I've found just these questions:

[In how many ways can five letters be posted in 4 boxes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370439/in-how-many-ways-can-five-letters-be-posted-in-4-boxes/)

[Distributing identical objects to identical boxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373202/distributing-identical-objects-to-identical-boxes)

For example I learned that the number of ways to distribute *labeled* balls into identical bins has something in common with the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). I expected my question to be somehow famous and with deep underlying math as well... Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Have a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130433/number-of-ways-of-distributing-k-balls-of-different-colors-all-balls-of-each-co?rq=1

Comment: It is famous, you are dealing with *partitions* into at most $n$ parts. Big literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my question answered:

Thank to @Shaktal and @AndréNicolas I learned that distributing identical objects into identical bins is closely connected with a part of number theory called *Integer partitions*. Here's an article that provides a nice amount of details, if anyone in the future is tackling the same topic:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)